# Problemas código Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Necesito hacer un programa para un trabajo de la universidad.

Es sobre una cafetera que entrega 2 opciones de sabor, muestra total a pagar por el usuario, solicita pago y entrega vuelto.

El problema que tengo es que todo es con selección por el usuario ingresando datos desde el teclado.

Cada vez que hace algo, tiene que cambiar de ventana para ejecutar lo siguiente.

Tengo como problema el "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in identation"

¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar sin tener que retabular todo?

PD: Utilicé como base un código que escribió un usuario de acá para responder una pregunta

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Cafetera():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana = Tk()
        self.ventana.geometry("400x500")
        self.ventana.title("Cafetera El Sol")

        self.opcion=IntVar(value=1)
        self.cantidad=IntVar(value=1)
        self.pago=IntVar(value=1)
        self.monto=IntVar(value=1)
        self.vuelto=IntVar(value=1)
        self.op1=IntVar(value=100)
        self.op2=IntVar(value=200)
        self.costo=IntVar(value=1)

        self.cantidad.trace('w',self.calcularCosto)
        self.pago.trace('w', self.calcular)
        self.monto.trace('w', self.calcular)
        
        self.calcularCosto()

        self.etiqueta1 = ttk.Label(self.ventana,text="Cafeteria el sol!!")
        self.etiqueta.pack()
        self.etiqueta2 = ttk.Label(self.ventana,text="1- arcoiris")
        self.etiqueta.pack()
        self.etiqueta3 = ttk.Label(self.ventana,text="2- zapallo")
        self.etiqueta.pack()
        self.etiqueta4 = ttk.Label(self.ventana,text="Escribe el número de la opcion: ")
        self.opcion = ttk.Entry(self.raiz,command=segunda,width=10)
```

Ésta es la función de la segunda ventana que se abre

```
    def segunda(self,*args):
        self.ventana.withdraw()
        self.ventana1=Tk()
        self.ventana1.geometry("300x300")
        self.ventana1.title("segunda ventana")
        
        self.calcularCosto()

        self.etiqueta1 = ttk.Label(self.ventana1,text="¿Cuántos quiere?")
        self.cantidad = ttk.Entry(self.ventana1, command=tercera,width=10)
```

Aquí es donde se genera la tercera ventana

```
    def tercera(self,*args):
        self.ventana1.withdraw()
        self.ventana2=Tk()
        self.ventana2.geometry("300x300")
        self.ventana2.title("tercera ventana")
        
        self.calcular()
        
        self.etiqueta1 = ttk.Label(self.ventana2,
                   text="Costo total:"+self.costo.get())
        self.etiqueta2 = ttk.Label(self.ventana2,
                   text="Ingrese monto a pagar por favor:")
        self.pago = ttk.Entry(self.ventana2, command=calcularVuelto, width=10)

        self.etiqueta3 = ttk.Label(self.ventana1,text="Su vuelto es:"+self.vuelto.get())
```

Acá lo que tengo es la funcion para calcular el costo o lo que va a pagar el usuario

```
    def calcularCosto(self, *args):
        
        error_dato = False
        total = 0
        try:
            opcion = int(self.opcion.get())
            cantidad = int(self.cantidad.get())
            op1 = int(self.op1.get())
            op2 = int(self.op2.get())
            costo = int(self.costo.get())
        except:
            error_dato = True    
        if not error_dato:
            if opcion == 1:
                costo = op1*cantidad

            else:
                costo = op2*cantidad

            self.costo.set(costo)
       
        else:
            self.costo.set("¡ERROR!")
```

Aquí tengo la función para calcular el vuelto que se le entrega  al usuario

```
    def calcularVuelto(self, *args):
        
        error_dato = False
        total = 0
        try:
            costo = int(self.costo.get())
            pago = int(self.pago.get())
            vuleto = int(self.vuelto.get())
        except:
            error_dato = True    
        if not error_dato:
            vuelto = pago-costo
            self.vuelto.set(vuelto)
        else:
            self.vuelto.set("¡ERROR!")

def main():
    mi_caf = Cafetera()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Según el editor que uses puedes tabular un grupo de lineas normalmente seleccionandolas todas y luego pulsando una combinación de teclas. Revisa la documentación de tu editor de código.

Answer (score 1):

**Si tienes una mezcla de *4 espacios en blanco* y *1 tabulación* para definir un nivel de identación** y lo que quieres es definir 1 nivel de identación solamente con *tabulaciones* puedes hacer un *script* que haga la sustitución. Si tu aplicación es *app.py*:

```
with open('app.py', 'r') as f:
    src = f.read()

fixed_src = src.replace('    ', '\t') # Identación = TAB
# fixed_src = src.replace('\t', '    ') # Identación = 4 espacios

with open('app_fixed.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(fixed_src)
```

**Esto funcionaría si hay una mezcla de "4 espacios" y "1 tabulación" para definir un nivel de identación.** Si hay partes del código en los que un nivel de identación es "1 espacio", otras en las que es "3 espacios", etc, el resultado no será satisfactorio.

Un saludo.